# Python - How can I execute a Microsoft Execel VBA macro embedded in a UserForm object

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I have a blank excel file with an embedded form as shown below:

[image]

That command button has VBA code behind it:

[image]

I am trying to call the macro CommandButton1_Click via python code:

```
from pywintypes import com_error
from xlwings import App

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_app = App(visible=True)
    wb = excel_app.books.open(r'C:\Users\kakkrah\Downloads\test.xlsm')
    try:
        wb.macro("CommandButton1_Click")()
    except com_error as ex:
        print(ex)
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

but am getting the following error:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Cannot run the macro ''test.xlsm'!CommandButton1_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Also tried:

```
wb.macro("UserForm1.CommandButton1_Click")()
```

but still fails:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Cannot run the macro ''test.xlsm'!UserForm1.CommandButton1_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

My macro settings also okay and the workbook isn't password protected in any way:

[image]

Comment: Looks like `CommandButton1_Click` is a private sub routine of the User Form. It has been a while since I used vba and have never tried what you are doing but my recommendations would be: 1) try making this a public sub routine; If that doesnt work 2) try creating a new public sub in a module or the workbook itself.

Comment: `CommandButton1_Click` isn't a macro.